# Помогите расставить знаки препинания в моём стихотворении

Tags: пунктуация

Так мало прожито,

Так много жаль.

И жизнь не сложена,

Теперь прощай.

---

Не буду ждать тебя,

Но ты вернись.

Прошу, приди ко мне,

И улыбнись.

---

Ты потерял меня,

На крыльях дня.

Не верил в то,

Что я люблю тебя.

---

Теперь забудь меня,

И всё пойми.

Не принял ты тогда,

Моей любви.

---

Я поняла, что я

Не для тебя.

Любви тебе большой

Желаю я.

---

Живи и счастлив будь

Ты без меня.

Сама пройду свой путь,

Я не твоя

---

И ты не мой теперь,

Что тут решать.

Закрою в сердце дверь,

И буду ждать

---

Когда придёт ко мне

Ещё любовь,

И унесёт меня

На небо вновь.

---

А может вот она,

Внутри меня

Наверно ждет, когда

Опомнюсь я

Answer (score 1):

Знаки - это запросто, а прочую хромоту оставим за кадром (как то: *ты потерял меня на крыльях дня... так много/го жаль*)...

---

---

Так мало прожито,

Так много жаль.

И жизнь не сложена...

Теперь прощай.

---

Не буду ждать тебя,

Но ты вернись.

Прошу, приди ко мне

И улыбнись.

---

Ты потерял меня

На крыльях дня.

Не верил в то,

Что я люблю тебя.

---

Теперь забудь меня

И всё пойми.

Не принял ты тогда

Моей любви.

---

Я поняла, что я

Не для тебя.

Любви тебе большой

Желаю я.

---

Живи и счастлив будь

Ты без меня.

Сама пройду свой путь,

Я не твоя

---

И ты не мой теперь,

Что тут решать?

Закрою в сердце дверь,

И буду ждать,

---

Когда придёт ко мне

Ещё любовь

И унесёт меня

На небо вновь.

---

А может, вот она,

Внутри меня

Наверно, ждёт, когда

Опомнюсь я.

---

---

Всё-таки вмешаюсь:

Строки

> Не верил в то,
>
> Что я люблю тебя -

должны выглядеть так:

*Не верил в то, что я*

*Люблю тебя.*

Разве не слышно, как ритмически совпадают

***Ты потерял меня... / Не верил в то, что я***...

И тоже о ритме:

> Я поняла, что я
>
> Не для тебя.
>
> Любви тебе большой
>
> Желаю я.

***Я поняла, что я... / Любви большой тебе...***

Слова переставить - и зазвучит.

---

А "унесет на небо" так похоже на безвременную кончину...

Answer (score 0):

Ну, если только расставить знаки, возможно, **так** подойдет?

Так мало прожито —
Так много жаль.
И жизнь не сложена,
Теперь — прощай!

Не буду ждать тебя,
Но ты вернись.
Прошу, приди ко мне
И улыбнись.

Ты потерял меня
На крыльях дня.
Не верил в то,
Что я люблю тебя.

Теперь забудь меня
И всё пойми.
Не принял ты тогда
Моей любви.

Я поняла, что я —
Не для тебя.
Любви тебе большой
Желаю я.

Живи и счастлив будь
Ты — без меня.
Сама пройду свой путь,
Я — не твоя.

И ты не мой теперь, —
Что тут решать? —
Закрою в сердце дверь
И буду ждать.

Когда придёт ко мне
Ещё любовь
И унесёт меня —
На небо — вновь?

А может, вот она —
Внутри меня,
Наверно, ждет, когда
Опомнюсь я...

Comment: С авторскими знаками не спорю. Но не могу согласиться  (1) с запятой после "и жизнь не сложена". Точка. Можно тире (если "прощай, потому что жизнь не сложена"). (2) с точкой после "и буду ждать". "Буду ждать, когда придёт ко мне ещё любовь". Именно так, а другая трактовка — от лукавого :))

Answer (score 0):

- Любовь уносит в небо, в облака, за облака. "На небо" — не очень удачно.
- После "я не твоя" нужен знак (восклицательный, точка).
- "Закрою в сердце дверь(,) И буду ждать" - запятая не нужна.
- После "внутри меня" нужен знак (точка, запятая).
- В самом конце стихотворения точка тоже не помешает.

Comment: Может лучше так?                                                       Когда придёт ко мне
Ещё любовь
И унесёт меня —
На крыльях вновь.

Comment: Гораздо лучше!!